# woocommerce checkout ajax 500 error

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have updated the woocommerce plugin in my site to version 2.6.0 recently and now I am facing a 500 error during checkout and this error message changed as per the payment method.

I have couple of payment methods as `Direct Bank Transfer` and `Cash On Delivery`.

When I use `Direct Bank Transfer` I am getting an error message error `Internal Server Error`and in browser console I am able to see the problem is with `http://example.com/checkout-2/?wc-ajax=checkout Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

On the other hand when I user `Cash On Delivery` as payment method I am seeing an error `String could not be parsed as XML`.

Anyone facing similar issues with woocommerce? not sure if this is because of plugin update or any other function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out myself finally. The problem is I messed up with the woocommerce email templates. When I undid all the changed in email templates the order slow started working normally.

During the debug process I noticed that though I get the `Internal Server Error` the order is getting posted successfully and is visible in woocommerce admin so I was getting the errors all this while due to changed email templates where I failed to pass the order data properly into emails.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Comment: Im having the exact same issue but cant work it out, ive not changed any of the email templates either. Which one was it breaking on?